# Where do I find the specs the Intel Core i5 M560?

Tags: intel

I would like to write a "Hello World" application from scratch. No C library, compiler, linker, nothing. Just a hex editor.

Processor: Intel Core i5 CPU M 560, 2.67GHz

Where can I find the specs of this processor (with the instruction codes, register values, etc).
(I am looking for something like the [DCPU specs](http://0x10c.com/doc/dcpu-16.txt) but for the Intel Core i5 M560).

I found the following document:
http://download.intel.com/products/processor/manual/325462.pdf
I am not sure that is the proper specs, and if yes, I would be interested in a "bare minimum to write hello world" version.

---

Update: as per great feedback in the comments, what I am now looking for is a **tutorial** on writing **assembly** for the given CPU.

Comment: Dor the record: do you want to write a hello-world bootloader/os or an application for an existing os. In the later case most of your hello world programm will probably be a call to the appropriate system function for output to console. And out of curiousity: Why would you want to write x86 in a hex editor? Afterall writing assembly and putting that through a common assembler should give the same results, why being much easier.

Comment: It sounds like you may want the [Software Developer Manuals](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html).

Comment: @Grizzly Thanks for the question about bootloader/os or application. For starter I would go for the application (I suppose it is the easiest of the two, isn't it?). Why in hex rather than assembly: because I would like to be as close as possible to the CPU. Writing in assembly means I rely on a compiler from my (very limited) understanding.

Comment: You don't get closer to machine when you write it as hex. Assembly mnemonics directly maps to hex codes. It is the same but ofcourse hex is less cognitive if you mean it.

Comment: @Arif Mert Akçakaya Thank you, I did not know there was a direct mapping between assembly and hex. I will write in assembly then.

Comment: If you use assembly over directly coding hex (which can easily drive you crazy, especially when you are new to machine code, so good call), you might want to change your question to tell us what you still need. Are you looking for an assembly manual (I'm pretty sure that would be a dublicate), a tutorial, ...?

Answer (score 3):

Seems like all you are looking for is a general x86 Assembly tutorial. This should provide you with all you need to create a Hello World application in Assembly. Please note, that you do not need to look for "Intel assembly" or anything, x86 is a general architecture that is being supported by both AMD and Intel.